# correct way to use <input type="file" capture /> on mobile devices

Tags: android, html, ios, input, mobile-browser

I am creating a form which has a file upload button to upload videos. Everything working as expected on Web, but on Mobile devices (both Android and iOS) I am having issues.

**on iOS**

The file upload button is directly opening device camera and there is no option to choose from "Gallery/Photos". Although, the recorded video is uploaded successfully.

**on Android**

Here the scenario is different. The upload button is showing all the options like Camera, Camcorder, Files etc. but after selecting `Camcorder` the file can't get uploaded to the server. Although, videos taken from Gallery are uploading successfully.

My file upload button

```
<input type="file" class="form-input-file" id="input-video-file" accept="video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/quicktime,video/*" capture="capture">
```

P.S. : I have tried using `capture` and `capture="camcorder"` as well but without  any luck.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The capture attribute takes 2 possible strings

- user
- environment

If the input type is 'file', it tells the browser to capture a new file, of a type specified by the 'accept' attribute, using a microphone or camera pointing to the user or away from the user, if there is one.

Eg Capture a new video file using the outward-facing device.

```
<input type="file" id="video-file" capture="environment" accept="video/*" />
```

Capture a new video file using the user-facing device.

```
<input type="file" id="video-file" capture="user" accept="video/*" />
```

To capture an existing video file drop 'capture' and 'accept' attributes, let the user navigate to the file they want.

```
    <input type="file" id="video-file" />
```